# Тормозят приложения при запуске из Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть небольшая проблема, которую я не могу решить.
Когда приложение билдится на реальном девайсе, напрямую через студию, то заметно подтупливает (даже если отключить устройство от пк и перезапустить, установленная апп остаётся такая же лагучая). Если сбилдить отдельно апк, залить на устройство и установить, то никаких лагов не наблюдается. Уже всю голову сломал.

Comment: instant run у вас включен?

Comment: Возможно проблема с драйверами, попробуйте другой смартфон или попробуйте пробилдить приложением WiFi ADB

Comment: @Jarvis_J Спасибо огромное! Вы решили мою проблему! Выключение Instant Run помогло.

Comment: пжлста) оформил как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выключите instant run:

`File => Settings => Build,Execution,Deployment => Instant run`, снять галочку с `Enable Instant Run`